# How to determine the location and boundary of a tile through its file name?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, qgis-processing, tiles

I generated a map tile set using the `Generate XYZ tiles (Directory)` tool in QGIS. When I then run `gdalinfo` on one of these images I see no reference to any spatial information:

```
Driver: JPEG/JPEG JFIF
Files: 1332.jpg
Size is 256, 256
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  256.0)
Upper Right (  256.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  256.0,  256.0)
Center      (  128.0,  128.0)
Band 1 Block=256x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 128x128
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
Band 2 Block=256x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 128x128
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
Band 3 Block=256x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 128x128
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
```

However, when loading it into a leaflet map the tiles are located at the correct location. To me it seems, that the tile file names include some spatial information like a reference to a grid.

If so: How can I determine the location and boundary of a tile through its file name? (in abstract code, formula or python script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question:

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

The magic word was `Slippy Map`